# How to specify the order of data displayed in BigQuery using the Union All function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-order-by

I am using the Union all function in Bigquery to display data from different tables.
Here is an example of what I am doing

```
(Select ErrorCode AS `Code`, ErrorDate AS `Date`
From Errors
Where id = x
Order By ErrorDate ASC)

UNION ALL
(SELECT 'Error Code', 'Error Meaning')
UNION ALL
(SELECT '1001', 'Restart your PC')
UNION ALL
(SELECT '1002', 'Check the cables')
```

What I am trying to achieve here is a table that displays all the error codes an account has encountered, and then at the bottom a simple print of all the error codes we have in our system and their meaning.

Now, when I run this code in BigQuery, for some reason the error codes and their meanings are showing up first, then the codes the system encountered. Example of result I am getting:

```
Error Code | Error Meaning
1001       | Restart your PC
1002       | Check the Cables
------------------------------
1003       | 2022-09-12
1001       | 2218-09-04
```

I want the error codes the system encountered to show up first and then the meaning. Something like this

```
Code       | Date
1003       | 2022-09-12
1001       | 2218-09-04
------------------------------
Error Code | Error Meaning
1001       | Restart your PC
1002       | Check the Cables
```

How can I specify this order in BigQuery? Moving the code portions up and down does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another sorting column

```
(Select ErrorCode AS `Code`, ErrorDate AS `Date`,1 as _sort
From Errors
Where id = x
Order By ErrorDate ASC)

UNION ALL
(SELECT 'Error Code', 'Error Meaning',2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT '1001', 'Restart your PC',3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT '1002', 'Check the cables',4)
ORDER BY  _sort
```

Qir´th a CTE it looks like

```
WITH CTE as (
(Select ErrorCode AS `Code`, ErrorDate AS `Date`,1 as _sort
From Errors
Where id = x
Order By ErrorDate ASC)

UNION ALL
(SELECT 'Error Code', 'Error Meaning',2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT '1001', 'Restart your PC',3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT '1002', 'Check the cables',4))
SELECT `Code`, `Date` FROM CTE
ORDER BY  _sort
```

Comment: The idea works. The only thing is that it adds another column in my report with the header '_sort' and then 1, 2,3,4 as table rows. Any idea about how to avoid the display of the number?

Comment: use a CTE of the union and make a select with only the wanted columns

Comment: Hey, I haven't used the CTE function and did some research online but could not find anything that would teach me how to use the function right. Any ideas about what changes I should make to my code?

Comment: i added the CTE  version

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! It works as expected now

Comment: you can now upvote ;) with more than 10 rep

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order in the select

Instead of:

```
Select ErrorCode AS `Code`, ErrorDate AS `Date`
```

try:

```
Select ErrorDate AS `Date`, ErrorCode AS `Code`
```